# React Error, happens when I use Redux connect in a children, how to bypass?Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Here is an Error:

Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, type, compare, WrappedComponent}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

It works just fine if I don't use connect in main.js and using connect in App.js doesn't make an Error, but once I use connect in main.js it throws me this error. What do I do wrong? And I'm using connect same way as in App.js Thank you

Here is sandBox https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-euler-7mpi7?file=/src/main.js

you can experience, just delete connect in main.js and it will start working

App.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import './styles/main.scss';
import './App.scss';

import routes from "./router/router";

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import {checkUser, fetchUsers, fetchPolls} from "./store/index";


function App (props) {
    useEffect(() => {
        let { loadUsers} = props
        loadUsers();
    }, [])

    let jsxRoutes = routes.map(el =>
        <Route
            path={el.url}
            exact={el.exact}
            key={el.url}>
            { el.component }
        </Route>
            )
    return (
            <Router>
                <div className="App">
                    <Switch>
                        { jsxRoutes }
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </Router>
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        users: state.users.data,
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        loadUsers: () => dispatch(fetchUsers())
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Main.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./main.scss"

import { connect } from "react-redux"


const Main = (props) => {
    return(
        <main>
            main pg
        </main>
    )
}



export default connect(null, null)(Main);
```

[image]

Comment: If you are not passing `mapStateToProps` `mapDispatchToProps` in connect then why you are even calling `connect`. You can directly use Main component in App component.

Comment: I'm passing, but I deleted what I pass, so it's easier to read. Error happens either I pass or don't pass anything. The main issue is I'm connecting something wrong

Answer (score 1):

In [App.js](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-euler-7mpi7?file=/src/App.js:197-332) try this instead:

```
let jsxRoutes = routes.map((el) => (
  <Route path={el.url} exact={el.exact} key={el.url} component={el.component} />
));
```

Or the shorter version: `<Route {...el} />`